# with rollup outputs last record

Tags: sql, rollup

When I use rollup on my select statement if returns the value of the last record in the query.

```
SELECT product_name, (item_price-discount_amount)*quantity AS "total_amount" 
FROM products JOIN  order_items  ON products.product_id=order_items.product_id 
GROUP BY products.product_name WITH ROLLUP;
```

The query return product_name and total_amount. the product_name for the roll up is null but the total_amount is the same as the last record. How do I get the sum of total_amount I need to use with rollup and I cant seem to fix it

Comment: what's your RDBMS? do you have any example input?

Comment: so what is the question here ??

Comment: If you need sum, then easiest way is to use sum() aggregate function. Like "sum((item_price-discount_amount)*quantity) as total_amount" or so.

Comment: Yet another victim of MySQL's group by extension. Unless product_Name is your primary key this query would have failed in all other DBMS and alerted you to the fact that you cannot have `item_price`, `discount_amount` and `quantity` in the select list unless they are contained in an aggregate function or the group by clause.